# How to interpolate with groupby object in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Original Dataframe

| a | b | yyyymm | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 200101 | 3000 |
| 1 | a | 200102 | np.nan |
| 1 | a | 200103 | np.nan |
| 1 | a | 200104 | 6000 |
| 1 | b | 200101 | np.nan |
| 1 | b | 200102 | np.nan |
| 1 | b | 200103 | np.nan |
| 1 | b | 200104 | 3000 |
| 2 | a | 200101 | 3000 |
| 2 | a | 200102 | np.nan |
| 2 | a | 200103 | np.nan |
| 2 | a | 200104 | np.nan |

I want the dataframe above to be like the following.

| a | b | yyyymm | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 200101 | 3000 |
| 1 | a | 200102 | 4000 |
| 1 | a | 200103 | 5000 |
| 1 | a | 200104 | 6000 |
| 1 | b | 200101 | np.nan |
| 1 | b | 200102 | np.nan |
| 1 | b | 200103 | np.nan |
| 1 | b | 200104 | 3000 |
| 2 | a | 200101 | 3000 |
| 2 | a | 200102 | np.nan |
| 2 | a | 200103 | np.nan |
| 2 | a | 200104 | np.nan |

I tried using the code below. But it seemed to be working but I found out that the first row in 2 consecutive worked but second row of it wasn't be filled.

```
df.price = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['price'].apply(
            lambda group: group.interpolate(method='linear', limit=2, limit_area='inside')
        )
```

Comment: So you only want to interpolate `price` for  a=1 and b="a"? Not the rest?

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'b': list('aaaabbbbaaaa'),
                   'yyyymm': [200101, 200102, 200103, 200104, 200101, 200102, 200103, 200104,
       200101, 200102, 200103, 200104],
                   'price': [3000,np.NaN,np.NaN,6000,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,3000,3000,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]
                  })

df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['price'].apply(
            lambda group: group.interpolate(method='linear', limit=2, limit_area='inside')
        )
```

output:

```
0     3000.0
1     4000.0
2     5000.0
3     6000.0
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
7     3000.0
8     3000.0
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```